# '' is not valid floating point value delphi

Tags: delphi, floating-point

error message thrown

[image]

```
` qConsulta2 := TQuery.Create(Application);
  qConsulta2.DatabaseName := 'BaseDato';
  qConsulta2.SQL.Text := 'select VALOR from PARAMETRO where codigoPARAMETRO  = ''IVA'' ';
  qConsulta2.open;
  qCompraDetalle.FieldByName('PORCENTAJE_IVA').AsFloat:=        qConsulta2.fieldbyname('valor').asfloat;
  qConsulta2.close;
  qConsulta2.free `
```

This threw me into execution this error, and do not know why, beforehand thank you very much for your time and help. Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: Still using BDE in 2013 ? Wow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the `qConsulta2.fieldbyname('valor').asfloat`
From my testing your error will occur if the VALOR column is text or varchar in the database table and it contains a Null or zero length string.

My test involved creating a table with VALOR_TEXT and VALOR_FLOAT columns in an MSAccess database.  VALOR_TEXT is defined as text and VALOR_FLOAT is defined a double. I wrote code for 4 test cases, 2 illustrate the error (Case1 and Case2) and 2 that provide solutions (Case 3 and Case4). The code is provided below.

```
procedure TForm1.Case1;
var
  f : double;
begin
  db.ExecSQL('delete from PARAMETRO');
  db.ExecSQL('insert into PARAMETRO (codigoPARAMETRO) values(''IVT'')');
// VALOR_FLOAT and VALOR_TEXT are null
  qConsulta2.SQL.Text := 'select * from PARAMETRO';
  qConsulta2.Open();
  f := qConsulta2.FieldByName('VALOR_FLOAT').AsFloat;
  ShowMessage('From Float '+FloatToStr(f));
  f := qConsulta2.FieldByName('VALOR_TEXT').AsFloat;
  ShowMessage('From Text '+FloatToStr(f));
end;

procedure TForm1.Case2;
var
  f : double;
begin
  db.ExecSQL('delete from PARAMETRO');
  db.ExecSQL('insert into PARAMETRO (codigoPARAMETRO,VALOR_TEXT) values(''IVT'','''')');
// VALOR_FLOAT is null and VALOR_TEXT is '' (zero length string)
  qConsulta2.SQL.Text := 'select * from PARAMETRO';
  qConsulta2.Open();
  f := qConsulta2.FieldByName('VALOR_FLOAT').AsFloat;
  ShowMessage('From Float '+FloatToStr(f));
  f := qConsulta2.FieldByName('VALOR_TEXT').AsFloat;
  ShowMessage('From Text '+FloatToStr(f));
end;
```

Case3 is directly applicable to fixing your code. By getting the data AsVariant, `NullStrictConvert := false` will allow Null values to be converted to float, integer, or string with out an exception.

```
procedure TForm1.Case3;
var
  f : double;
begin
  NullStrictConvert := false;
  db.ExecSQL('delete from PARAMETRO');
  db.ExecSQL('insert into PARAMETRO (codigoPARAMETRO) values(''IVT'')');
// VALOR_FLOAT and VALOR_TEXT are null
  qConsulta2.SQL.Text := 'select * from PARAMETRO';
  qConsulta2.Open();
  f := qConsulta2.FieldByName('VALOR_FLOAT').AsFloat;
  ShowMessage('From Float '+FloatToStr(f));
  f := qConsulta2.FieldByName('VALOR_TEXT').AsVariant;
  ShowMessage('From Text '+FloatToStr(f));
end;
```

Case4 provides a method for avoiding data conversion as long as the source and target columns are the same type.  If they are not the same type, data conversion errors can still occur.

```
procedure TForm1.Case4;
var
  f : double;
begin
  NullStrictConvert := false;
  db.ExecSQL('delete from PARAMETRO');
  db.ExecSQL('insert into PARAMETRO (codigoPARAMETRO) values(''IVT'')');
// VALOR_FLOAT and VALOR_TEXT are null
  qConsulta2.SQL.Text := 'select * from PARAMETRO';
  qConsulta2.Open();
  f := qConsulta2['VALOR_FLOAT'];
  ShowMessage('From Float '+FloatToStr(f));
  f := qConsulta2['VALOR_TEXT'];
  ShowMessage('From Text '+FloatToStr(f));
  // avoid data conversion
  qCompraDetalle.Open();
  qCompraDetalle.Append;
  qCompraDetalle['PORCENTAJE_IVA'] := qConsulta2['VALOR_TEXT'];
  qCompraDetalle.Post;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure qConsulta2.fieldbyname('valor').asfloat is not empty.

Comment: By empty, I guess you mean `NULL`? Calling `AsFloat` on a Null float field will return `0`, not an error.

Comment: rkawano How do I ensure that is not empty? FieldByName and I did in the event FormCreate

    DateSeparator: = '/';
       DecimalSeparator: =; '.'
       LongDateFormat: = 'dd / mm / yyyy';
       ThousandSeparator: = '';
       TimeSeparator: = ':';


but it keeps throwing error

Comment: Run this query direct on your database: SELECT * FROM Parametro WHERE Valor IS NULL OR Valor = ''    It will show to you if any records are empty.

Comment: @JeissonNiño by opening the help and searching for the "null" word - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TField_Properties

Answer (score 1):

You must check if your query actually returned records:

```
qConsulta2 := TQuery.Create(Application);
try
  qConsulta2.DatabaseName := 'BaseDato';
  qConsulta2.SQL.Text := 'select VALOR from PARAMETRO where codigoPARAMETRO  = ''IVA'' ';
  qConsulta2.open;
  if not qConsulta2.EOF then  
   qCompraDetalle.FieldByName('PORCENTAJE_IVA').AsFloat:= qConsulta2.fieldbyname('valor').asfloat;
  qConsulta2.close;
finally 
  qConsulta2.free 
end;
```

or if you want to make sure there is always a record returned, use the SQL `COALESCE` command:

```
qConsulta2 := TQuery.Create(Application);
try
  qConsulta2.DatabaseName := 'BaseDato';
  qConsulta2.SQL.Text := 'select COALESCE(VALOR, 0) AS valor from PARAMETRO where codigoPARAMETRO  = ''IVA'' ';
  qConsulta2.open;
  qCompraDetalle.FieldByName('PORCENTAJE_IVA').AsFloat:= qConsulta2.fieldbyname('valor').asfloat;
  qConsulta2.close;
finally 
  qConsulta2.free 
end;
```

**UPDATE**

Wild Guess here, since you did not provide your database details: if your `VALOR` field in the `PARAMETRO` table is actually a Varchar type then you could have an empty string instead of `NULL` :

```
qConsulta2 := TQuery.Create(Application);
try
  qConsulta2.DatabaseName := 'BaseDato';
  qConsulta2.SQL.Text := 'select VALOR from PARAMETRO where codigoPARAMETRO  = ''IVA'' ';
  qConsulta2.open;
  if qConsulta2.FieldByName('VALOR').AsString <> '' then  
   qCompraDetalle.FieldByName('PORCENTAJE_IVA').AsFloat:= qConsulta2.fieldbyname('valor').asfloat;
  qConsulta2.close;
finally 
  qConsulta2.free 
end;
```

Comment: Yes, OP should check for empty data set, but even if it's empty, it will return `0`, not error.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, no it will AV because qConsulta2.fieldbyname('valor') will be nil because there is no recordset returned?

Comment: I guess it could depend on the implementation of your particular `TQuery` component, but it should simply be `NULL`, not raise an AV.